# Eigenvectors solution for unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, unitary-matrices

Is the method of solving for an eigenvector/value of a unitary matrix different from solving for a regular finite matrix?

Comment: Why do you think that it might be different?

Comment: What is a "regular finite matrix"?

Comment: The paper-and-pencil method is the same, but there may be some computer algorithms that take advantage of the matrix being unitary

Comment: If taking a matrix logarithm is convenient, the we can reduce the problem to finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix.  A well-known algorithm that works for Hermitian matrices is [the Jacobi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_eigenvalue_algorithm)